# How do i change Icon on FAB and reposition item to the end/right on Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

[BottomBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ns1Al.png)
So, i tried to make a BottomNavBar and play around with it, but when I use Icon property on  FloatingActionButton it does not register, Also I want to reposition all item on the Bottom Nav for exercise but can't figure it out

```
bottomBar = {
                    BottomAppBar(backgroundColor = materialBlue700, cutoutShape = CircleShape) {
                        Text(text = "BottomAppBar")
                        Button(
                                onClick = { },
                        backgroundColor = Color.Yellow) {
                        Row {
                            Spacer(Modifier.preferredSize(4.dp).padding(32.dp))
                            Text("Button")
                        }
                    }
                        IconButton(onClick = {
                            scaffoldState.drawerState.open()
                        }) {
                            Icon(Icons.Filled.Menu)
                        }
                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f, true))

           

 }
        },
        floatingActionButtonPosition = FabPosition.End,
        isFloatingActionButtonDocked = true,
        floatingActionButton = {
            FloatingActionButton(
                    shape = CircleShape,
                    onClick = {},
            ) {
                Icon(asset = Icons.Filled.Add)
            }
        }
```

Edit: by "it does not register" I meant that the Card does not show on the Preview

Comment: What Icon property of FloatingActionButton does not register?, and internally bottom bar content is placed inside Row.

Comment: what is the meaning of "it doesn't register", And how you want to reposition items on BottomNav. Can you be more clear about your question?

Comment: "it doesn't register" I mean that it does not show on the Preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally, `BottomAppBar` user `Row` to align the components(Same as `LinearLayout` with Orientation Horizontal), so you need to add the item accordingly.

Ex:

```
@Composable
fun BottomBarSample() {
    Scaffold(
        drawerContent = { },
        topBar = { },
        floatingActionButton = {
            FloatingActionButton(
                shape = CircleShape,
                onClick = {},
            ) {
                Icon(asset = Icons.Filled.Add)
            }
        },
        floatingActionButtonPosition = FabPosition.End,
        isFloatingActionButtonDocked = true,
        bodyContent = { },
        bottomBar = {
            BottomAppBar(backgroundColor = purple500, cutoutShape = CircleShape) {
                IconButton(onClick = {
//                    scaffoldState.drawerState.open()
                }) {
                    Icon(Icons.Filled.Menu, tint = Color.Red)
                }

                Text(text = "BottomAppBar")

                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.preferredSize(16.dp))

                Button(
                    onClick = { },
                    backgroundColor = Color.Red
                ) {
                    Row() {
                        Text("Button")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    )
}
```

And the Preview will look like this.[image]